# How to pass ID to items

Tags: python, django

I am having a problem with my code. When i add two item with same url in my cart then i increase the quantity of the second item, it increases only the first item instead of the second item in cart. I think in my code the  . first()   is the problem. How do i add the ID of each items to my code. My code below.

[image]

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    old_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = HTMLField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
        db_table = 'items'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Items'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"

class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

    def colors(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='color')

VAR_CATEGORIES = (
    ('size', 'size'),
    ('color', 'color'),
    ('package', 'package'),
    )

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, 
    default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


def product(request, id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=id)
    print(item)

    context = {
        'product': item,
    }
    return render(request,'product.html', context)

def add_to_cart(request, id):

    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)

    item_var = [] #item variation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        qty = request.POST['quantity']
        for items in request.POST:
            key = items
            val = request.POST[key]
            print(key,val)

            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(
                    item=item,
                    category__iexact=key,
                    title__iexact=val
                )
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass

    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    print(order_item_qs)

    if len(item_var) > 0:
        for items in item_var:
            order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                        variation__exact=items,
                    )

    if order_item_qs.exists():
        order_item = order_item_qs.first()
        order_item.quantity = qty
        order_item.save()
        print(order_item_qs)

    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_item.variation.add(*item_var)
        order_item.quantity = qty
        order_item.save()
        order_item.id

        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            #check if the order item is in the order
            if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
                order.items.quantity = qty
                order.items.add(order_item)
                messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
                return redirect("shop:order-summary")
        else:
            ordered_date = timezone.now()
            order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
    return redirect("shop:order-summary")


def update_cart(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        qty = request.POST['quantity']

    order_item_qs= OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )

    if order_item_qs.exists():
        item = order_item_qs.first()
        item.quantity = qty
        item.save()

    return redirect("shop:order-summary")

Product Template:

    <form method="POST" action="{{ product.get_add_to_cart_url }}">
              {% csrf_token %}

           <p>
              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
              <input type="number" value="1" name="quantity" id="qty1" 
    class="quantity_class" min="1" required>
              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
          </p> 

              {% if product.variation_set.all %}

              {% if product.variation_set.sizes %}
            <select class="form-control" name="size">
              {% for items in product.variation_set.sizes %}
              <option value="{{ items.title|lower }}">{{ items.title|capfirst }} 
   </option>
              {% endfor %}                      
            </select>
           {% endif %}

           {% if product.variation_set.colors %}
            <select class="form-control" name="color">
              {% for items in product.variation_set.colors %}
              <option value="{{ items.title|lower }}">{{ items.title|capfirst }} 
   </option>
              {% endfor %}                      
            </select>
           {% endif %}

           {% endif %}

            <hr>

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md my-2 p" type="submit" 
    value="Add to cart">

            </form>

Order summary template:

    {% for order_item in object.items.all %}

    <form method="POST" action="{{ order_item.item.get_update_cart_url }}">
              {% csrf_token %}

            <p>
              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
              <input type="number" value="{{ order_item.quantity }}" 
    name="quantity" id="qty1" class="quantity_class" min="1" required>
              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
          </p>
              <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md my-2 p" type="submit" 
    value="Update cart">

            </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The two items are different, since one is size Large and the other size Small. How are you otherwise going to know what was ordered? Your post request is submitting the `id` of the item (I don't see any `slug` in your code), so the `id` should be different for both items.

Comment: oh sorry, i just edited my question again. I meant to say the item url. The two item have same url (example: url: product-shirt), both with different sizes (example: small and large). But when i try to increases the second item quantity of the product with large size to 2, it automatically increases the first item quantity to 2. I think the problem is the  .first()  that is in my code. How can i be able to increase each quantity for the both item.

Comment: Again, both items should have a different SKU or ID or something to differentiate them. That's what you should use in your POST and to fetch the correct one from the database. They can't be the same `Item`, which looks like it's what you're doing.

Comment: I just want users to be able to increase quantity for the both item, example, if the user want to buy 2 large shirt and also same item, 3 large shirt.

Comment: 2 large shirt + 3 large shirt of the exact same product/color etc... is 5 large shirts. It doesn't make sense that those are different line items. In any shop, when you add the exact same item to your cart, it gets shown on the same line. What you say in your comment is different than what you show in your question (2 small sweater + 1 large sweater, those are different items).

Comment: Your code should work if each `Item` that can be ordered has a unique ID. ie.. if the small sweater has a different ID than a large sweater, your code should just work.

Comment: No... when someone orders for a sweater shirt e.g  (1 small sweater shirt) and (1 large sweater shirt).  If i want to increase the quantity to 2 of (1 large sweater shirt) it automatically increases the (1 small sweater shirt) to (2 small sweater shirt), instead of (2 large sweater shirt). As shown in the image above. This is the problem.

Comment: how can i set a different ID to the item? I already have unique=True in my model.

Comment: Does a small sweater have a different id than a large sweater?

Comment: How do i fix this problem, how do i pass different id to the item. I know that is the problem with my code. Or am i missing something in my code?

Comment: I don't know, you're not showing the code of the view that displays the products and you're not showing the code that submits the update and you're not showing your `Item` model. Again, if you have two different sweaters on your page, they should have a different `Item` (id) in your database. If that's not the case, you need to change your database/models so that each unique product is also unique in your database, with a different id. As I said, there's nothing wrong with the code you're showing here. It's the code that displays the items and how users select an item that's wrong.

Comment: I have updated my questions, check it now.

Comment: You need to rethink your design here. `OrderItem` has a m2m field to `Variation` but that doesn't make sense. It should have a `OneToOneField` probably, so that you make a different `OrderItem` for each variation. And you should submit the variation in the POST request as well, so the combination `id`, `variation` is unique and determines which `OrderItem` is being updated. Alternatively, you could create a new table that contains all the variations of your products as unique rows with their unique SKU (and inventory), which is the more usual way to do things.

Comment: I submitted the variation in the POST request, please i just updated the add to cart to my question. please check now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django, but I think @dirkgroten has a point. This just screams design issues to me, not programming problem.

Comment: Yes i know there is a point to what @dirkgroten said, so i will try what he said and see if things work perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work, adding item to cart works just fine. But clicking on the button + to increase quantity do not work for each of same item when added twice in cart, only for just only the first item. I can only make this work when I change the quantity in the admin.

Comment: Finally I have solved the problem, I made a different design, using form to update the quantity with different variations passing the ID of each product.